# Виджет исчезает сразу при загрузки страницы

Tags: python, pyside2

Хочу завязать на нажатие кнопки анимацию исчезновения виджета, но она срабатывает сразу при запуске программы в чём фокус пока не разобрался.

```
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtWidgets


class PanelConnect(QtWidgets.QWidget):
  def __init__(self):
     self.panelWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.panelWidget)
    self.hostLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel('Host: ')
    self.portLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel('Port: ')
    self.userLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel('User: ')
    self.passLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel('Pass: ')

    self.hostLine = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
    self.portLine = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
    self.userLine = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
    self.passLine = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()

    self.loginBut = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Login')

    self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.hostLabel, 0, 0)
    self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.hostLine, 0, 1)
    self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.portLabel, 0, 2)
    self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.portLine, 0, 3)
    self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.userLabel, 1, 0)
    self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.userLine, 1, 1)
    self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.passLabel, 2, 0)
    self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.passLine, 2, 1)
    self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.loginBut, 1, 2, 2, 3)

    self.panelWidget.setMaximumHeight(120)
    self.panelWidget.setObjectName('stylePanel')

    self.strStyle = str('#stylePanel {border: 1px solid #C0C0C0; border-radius: 10px;}'
                        'QLineEdit {border: 2px solid; border-radius: 5px; font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold;}'
                        'QLineEdit:focus {border: 2px solid #FFD700;}'
                        'QLabel {font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold;}'
                        'QPushButton {border: 2px solid #000000; border-radius: 10px;'
                        'background-color: #ffffff; font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold;}'
                        'QPushButton:pressed{background-color: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1,'
                        'stop: 0 #000000, stop: 0.5 #000000, stop: 0.51 #000000, stop: 1 #000000); color: #ffffff}'
                        'QPushButton:flat { border: none; }')

    self.panelWidget.setStyleSheet(self.strStyle)

    self.hostLine.setMinimumWidth(300)
    self.hostLine.setMinimumHeight(30)

    self.passLine.setMaximumWidth(300)
    self.passLine.setMinimumWidth(300)
    self.passLine.setMinimumHeight(30)

    self.userLine.setMaximumWidth(300)
    self.userLine.setMinimumWidth(300)
    self.userLine.setMinimumHeight(30)

    self.portLine.setMaximumWidth(100)
    self.portLine.setMinimumWidth(100)
    self.portLine.setMinimumHeight(30)

    self.loginBut.setMinimumHeight(60)
    self.loginBut.pressed.connect(self.animateHide())


@QtCore.Slot()
def animateHide(self):
    eff = QtWidgets.QGraphicsOpacityEffect(self.panelWidget)
    self.panelWidget.setGraphicsEffect(eff)

    self.animateBut = QtCore.QPropertyAnimation(eff, b'opacity')
    self.animateBut.setDuration(2500)
    self.animateBut.setStartValue(1)
    self.animateBut.setEndValue(0)
    self.animateBut.setEasingCurve(QtCore.QEasingCurve.OutBack)
    self.animateBut.start(QtCore.QPropertyAnimation.DeleteWhenStopped)
```

Answer (score 0):

Заменил

```
self.loginBut.pressed.connect(self.animateHide())
```

на

```
self.loginBut.pressed.connect(self.animateHide)
```